# SQL Server linked server try catch not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are trying to post some data from SQL Server to Oracle using a linked server. The data inserts properly at times, but at times it fails. Not sure why it is failing.

I kept a TRY catch block in the SQL Server stored procedure, but is is not catching. Could you please help me with this?

Browsed several sites in this regard, but somehow, it did not work

My code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (SomeDB, 'SELECT a, s, d, f, e FROM XYZ')  
    SELECT
        a, s, d, f, @e
    FROM    
        @tbltest
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting, try catch wont catch most of the errors

Comment: I am not getting any error, If i try to manual insert the same data it works

Comment: can you please elaborate on this then `The data inserts properly at times, but at times it fails`

Comment: Some times the Stored Procedure is inserting the data to the Linked Server table , but sometimes it is failing. I can confirm that because before inserting the data to Linked server, we pushed data to staging tables locally.  data in Staging table exists  but not in Linked server tables.

Comment: with out any data ,one can only guess..may be you need to debug those times

Comment: Yes I tried to debug, When i manually insert , it gets inserted

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately BEGIN TRY/ END TRY block does not catch Linked server-related errors if you use such commands like INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(....) or SELECT FROM OPENQUERY(...)

But you may try convert your SQL-request into string and use EXEC [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) 'INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(....)' OR EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT FROM  OPENQUERY' inside BEGIN TRY/ END TRY block.
For example:

```
-- Script start
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql 
         'INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (SomeDB, ''SELECT a, s, d, f, e FROM XYZ'')  
          SELECT a, s, d, f, @e
          FROM @tbltest'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     -- Handle error here, for example
     SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
-- End
```

If it doesn't work with table variables (@tbltest), try using temporary tables, they are usually also faster.

Also you may find useful to test Linked Server availability before starting all this stuff with:

```
EXEC sp_testlinkedserver N'SomeDB';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probably gonna want a structure like this

```
BEGIN TRY 
    INSERT INTO [database]..[Table]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
       SELECT 
           [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] 
       FROM 
           [database]..[SourceTable] 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     INSERT INTO [database]..[ErrorTable]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
        SELECT 
            [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] 
        FROM [database]..[SourceTable]
END CATCH
```

Comment: I am using Linked query to insert , and I have TRY catch, But my TRY catch is in general not specific to this query, do you want me to do it in Specific to that query

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
BEGIN TRY 
    INSERT INTO [database]..[Table]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
       SELECT 
           a, s, d, f, e
       FROM 
           LINE_INTG.STG_PRDCTN_RUN_SHIFT_DTL 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     INSERT INTO [database]..[ErrorTable]([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
        SELECT 
            a, s, d, f, e 
        FROM LINE_INTG.STG_PRDCTN_RUN_SHIFT_DTL
END CATCH
```